# django template falling into unexpected logic

Tags: django, templates, django-templates, django-views

I have a view that is supposed to be gathering all the objects for a currently authenticated user from three tables `TSFH`, `TSUH`, and `TSJH` and gather all those objects for the currently logged in user, if that user exists.

However, my `view` logic is currently falling into the `else` statement it appears.

Can someone help me debug why this might be happening?

My tables have data for the currently logged in user, so I am not sure why this is happening.

**Views.py**

```
def SHO(request): 
    TSUH = TSUH.objects.filter(FKToUser_id=request.user).all()
    TSFH = TSFH.objects.filter(FKToUser_id=request.user).all()
    TSJH = TSJH.objects.filter(FKToUser_id=request.user).all()

    return render(request, 'page.html', {
         'TSUH':HasTSUH,
         'TSFH':HasTSFH,
         'TSJH':HasTSJH

    })
```

**templates/page.html**

```
{% autoescape on %}
{% if HasTSUH %}
    {% for t in HasTSUH %}
        <li>{{ t.begin }}<span></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% elif HasTSFH %}
    {{ HasTSFH }}
{% elif TSJH %}
    {{ TSJH }}
{% else %}
    It appears you haven't done anything yet.
{% endif %}
```

However it keeps displaying:
`It appears you haven't done anything yet.`

what am i doing wrong here? thanks

Comment: your code is mixing `HasTSUH` and `TSUH` all over the place. With what you wrote in your question, your view should crash with `HasTSUH not defined error`. And in your template you also mix the two. The keys of your dict are `TSUH` so that's what you should use in your template (you do it for `TSJH` for some strange reason)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The names in the template are the keys of the context dict. You've used `TSUH`, `TSFH`, and `TSJH`, without the `Has`.

Comment: So use without the `Has` ?

Comment: Well, be consistent.